# Using RadioButton with RadioButtonGroup in a DataGridColumn (in a quiz application)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

I am having some issues to properly use several RadioButton components along with a RadioButtonGroup in my quiz application (when they are rendered via ItemRenderer under DataGridColumn).

The quiz page displays a question along with 4 possible answers which represented by RadioButton components (tied with a unique RadioButtonGroup). A quiz usually contains many multiple choice questions.

Everything works fine until I navigate to the next question and return to the previous question; then I could see my former answer selection in the radio button although when I change my answer and select a different radio button it keeps my old selection and add the new one, which is entirely unreasonable (since RadioButtonGroup should enforce selection of one option only).

Here is how I define the DataGridColumn:

```
<mx:DataGrid y="141" height="373" dataProvider="{currentQuestion.answers}" id="answersGrid" visible="false"  styleName="NoStyleDataGrid" useRollOver="false" headerHeight="0" width="381" x="461" variableRowHeight="true">           
          <mx:columns>                                
            <mx:DataGridColumn  width="20" dataField="key">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                      <mx:Component>
                        <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" top="0">
                            <mx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    import mx.core.Application;
                                ]]>
                            </mx:Script>

                            <mx:RadioButton id="rb" value="{data.number}" selected="{outerDocument.isSelected(data.number,rb)}"  group="{outerDocument.getGroup()}" click="outerDocument.setAnswerState(event,data.number)" width="100%" height="30" x="12" y="0" />                                

                        </mx:Canvas>                                    
                      </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

I make sure each question has its own unique Group to contain the RadioButton components (as answers) using this code:

```
        public function getGroup():RadioButtonGroup{                
            if(radioGroupMap[currentQuestion.key]!=null){                                       
                return radioGroupMap[currentQuestion.key] as RadioButtonGroup;                                      
            }                               
            radioGroupMap[currentQuestion.key] = new RadioButtonGroup();
            return radioGroupMap[currentQuestion.key] as RadioButtonGroup;
        }
```

This code works fine as long as I do not go to the next question and return to the previous one.

Appreciate any help on this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could show the screen shot of the issue or add a sample running application, it would be clear to understand your problem.

Comment: My first question is why do you use itemrenderers and a datagrid instead of plain containers with radiobuttongroups :) And second question - when you say "I navigate to the next question and return to the previous question" do you mean scrolling the datagrid ? Because if so, this probably happens because itemrenderers are reused all the time - when you scroll and an itemrenderer goes offscreen it is not deleted but reused for new items. So when you scroll up and down it might happen that you have some stuff from previous questions in there.

Comment: Maybe I should be using plain containers, I initially used datagrid since I display an unknown number of answers and I need each answer to contain the answer number/letter, the content, and wrong/right indication. This seems to be classic use of data grid. I can use other containers although I will have to dynamically build the UI since the number of answers is changing between questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, it appears that item renderers containing RadioButtons along with RadioButtonGroup on data grid column are not a good design choice. Apparently more item renderers are created than actually needed due to  performance reasons which makes the UI act in an unpredictable manner.

I used VBOX instead and created the RadioButton along with the RadioButtonGroup dynamically using ActionScript. Here is some code example:

```
            function populateAnswers(){
                var rbg:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();
                for each ( var ans:Answer in currentQuestion.answers){
                    var row:HBox = new HBox();
                    var rb:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
                    rb.group = rbg;
                    rb.id = ""+ans.number;
                    var num:int = ans.number;
                        rb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,setAnswerState);
                rb.selected = isSelected(ans.number);                       
                        row.addChild(rb);                       

                    var answerBoby:Text = new Text();
                    answerBoby.enabled = false;
                    answerBoby.styleName = "readOnlyTA";
                    answerBoby.selectable = false;
                    answerBoby.htmlText = ans.body;
                    row.addChild(answerBoby);
                    quizAnswersPanel.addChild(row);                     

                }
```